# React update nested object in state with variables identificator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i am unable to update nested object state in react. When i am trying to do this i am getting error in all childs (Undefined props from parrent).
Here is my code:

```
    updateColumn(newSubject,dayId,order){
        console.log("tu som");
        console.log(newSubject);
        console.log(dayId);
        console.log(order);
        console.log(this.state.schedule);
        //Problematic part:
        let newSchedule = this.state.schedule;
        newSchedule.days[dayId].slots[order] = newSubject;
        console.log("newSchedule");
        console.log(newSchedule);

        this.setState({schedule:this.state.schedule});
        console.log("this new state");
        console.log(this.state.schedule);
        //State changed but error shows
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you actually getting? Also, you probably want to keep your nested object immutable. Right now you are changing it in place, which could prevent React from detecting a change and rendering it properly.

Comment: SubjectColumn.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'acronym' of undefined

Comment: It is my child error. It is using props.subject.acronym

Comment: But i am changing all schedule state. Or not?

Comment: That particular error is occurring because "subject" is undefined, based on what you're describing. Without knowing more about the shape of your data before and after the update, it's hard to pin down why, although it seems like your newSubject may be incomplete.

Comment: You aren't changing the schedule to a new object. You are taking the old schedule, changing it, and setting the schedule back. The exact same JS object is still being used. Hamza's response below shows how to use the spread operator to rebuild it in an immutable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
this.setState({...this.state, schedule: {
  ...this.state.schedule,
  days: {
     ...this.state.schedule.days,
     [dayId]: dayId,
     slots: {
      ...this.state.schedule.days.slots,
      [order] : newSubject
   }
})
```

Comment: This makes assumptions about the shape of the data. You don't know if `days` is an object or an array, same with `slots`. Also, presumably the value of the [daysId] key should be the day itself, not the id.

Comment: Yes, I don't know the shape of the data, That's why I said to try my answer hoping that days and slots are objects. But thank you for the comment

Comment: At the end with this solution i have a big trouble with my code... I put shape of data in post... And i create new answer about this becouse i am not sure if it is problem whout you adviced me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981764/react-state-data-change-themselfs-after-i-update-state

Comment: days => arrays of objects and slots arrays of objects